# How to bring back Android app in Emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I made a big mistake today i unfortunately unstalled android app from emulator device and now i am unable to find the app everytime i rebuld project and run my emulator android app doesnt show up in emulator device which is the reason why i am not able to see logcat please help. I dont have a running device i use only emulator please help me how to get android app on emulator again!

I also tried running app in android phone but it takes original apk file while i uninstalled it it never updates please tell me what can i do ?

Comment: Logcat output begins being generated long before any attempt to run your app.  If you IDE will only show it subsequently, then learn to run adb logcat in a terminal/command window.  Installation generates log messages too, so that may help you determine why your attempt to re-install your app doesn't seem to be working.  Or it is possible you revised your project in such a way that it no longer lists a launcher activity in its manifest.

Comment: So how to get it back in laucher activity manifest any help will save me

Comment: Try building a very simple app from the sdk samples or using the new app wizard.  Compare to your manifest.  Read the logcat generated *during* the install attempt.  If you are still stuck, edit your AndroidManifest.xml into the body of your question.

Comment: Sure will give a try and let you know about the progress :)

Comment: Chris Stratton thanks a lot bro for your help my problem is resolved now first i tried doing completely new project hello world program initially i was using Nexus 5 virtual device this is the same device where i uninstalled my previous app. Now i created a new AVD nexus 4 and launced it and i can see my app again. So i opened my old project and launched with nexus 4 it works now thanks :) this community is really good and helping sorry for long comment ;)